# My apache server isn't working on MAMP, what should the settings be?

Tags: mamp

I'm trying to setup my first `WordPress` blog in `MAMP`

I'm locating all files in `htdocs` folder.

My apache port is set too 8888 but it isn't lighting up when I start the start the servers. What should they be set to?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy `Wordpress` in localhost, you will need to start your Apache server and your MySQL database.

To perform the deploy, the first step is to create your MySQL database where all Wordpress data is going to be stored.

Then, put `Wordpress` folder (the content of the .zip you should download it from official Wordpress website https://wordpress.org/download/) inside `htdocs`of your MAMP application.

Then, access to http://localhost:8888 and a set up webpage for Wordpress must appear.

Go step by step and then your Wordpress will be deployed.

If you have any extra doubt, please share with us or take a look at that official guide http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Detailed_Instructions

Comment: Thanks butI can't get my apache server to work though, I have my wordpress file in htdocs. (on Yosmite) I found this link http://codesoap.com/mamp-pro-apache-and/ and tried changing envvars to _envvars but still it won't work.